# Please help me....I want to know how to code for background subtraction

Tags: opencv, background-subtraction

I'm just getting started with OpenCV. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026752/efficient-background-subtraction-with-opencv), and I'm trying to find where that code came from. Any ideas?

Comment: I *think* this is what Linetor meant, but if anyone else has a better idea feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have reference image of the background then you could try to make an average of first `n` frames and use such resultant image as a reference. This number, `n`,  could be 20 or similar and it should be enough if the scene isn't too complex. I recommend you to read a chapter about background subtraction in  official OpenCV book ([http://www.amazon.com/Learning-OpenCV-Computer-Vision-Library/dp/0596516134](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)) as there are some of other similar techniques presented.