# Per Pixel Thresholding

Tags: image-processing, opencv, threshold, background-subtraction

I was wondering if it is possible in opencv to have a threshold value per pixel. For example p(x,y) should be above 100 and then p(x+1,y) should be above 101.

You can see this as background subtraction. So that everything in front of the background remains.

I was thinking something like this. I have an image and then the other image. I subtract them. This means everything that is left should be above the threshold.

For example:

[image]

At the right side is the image taken when the camera (kinect) is launched. Then the image to the left is the current camera feed - the image at the left side.

the code :

> cvSub(depth, depthInit, difference, null);

Since nothing changes this should be more black (I can understand there is some noise)

Could this be because there are negative values left or something ?

Thx in advance

Comment: You could create a matrix t with the same size as your image  that contains all the thresholds and then just do `Mat res = p > t;`. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: How is this possible in opencv with IplImages ?

Comment: Oh sorry. I was talking about the C++ API and the cv::Mat types. I don't know if something like this is possible using the C API.

Comment: In fact it is in javacv. But i tried with and iplimage and cvMat neither seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `cvCmp`  ([Docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#cmp))

```
// make sure threshold is zero to start with
cvZero(thresholded);
// for pixels where current > background, sets thresholded = high value
cvCmp(current, background, thresholded, CV_CMP_GT);
```

Comment: I suppose this does the trick, though i can't completely confirm since my results consist of a lot of noise due to the Kinect.

Comment: Just stick something in there :)  cvSub *should* truncate negative values to 0 (it does in C).  You can get the same effect by doing cvAbsDiff, cvCmp, and then cvAnd the results.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026752/efficient-background-subtraction-with-opencv) question. It helps you?

You can also try to sweep pixel per pixel, using a for, and increment the thresholds...