# Detect significantly distinct image from a set, such as with OpenCV or SimpleCV

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, motion-detection, simplecv

I have still images captured over the course of one night by a webcam. The majority are identical, since the lighting in the images is uniform. However, some are significantly different from the rest - they have visible human movement through the frame.

How can I **detect which of the images are significantly distinct**, so that the movement will be included in them? Better yet, is there a way of specifically **detecting motion**?

I'm guessing that a library like OpenCV or SimpleCV can accomplish this easily, but I'm not limited to using those ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SimpleCV,

```
cam = Camera()
prev = cam.getImage()
while True:
    current = cam.getImage()
    fs = current.findMotion(prev, method="LK")
    if fs: #if there's motion
        print "motion found"
    prev = current
```

`Image.findMotion()` uses Optical Flow to detect motion. You can use this very easily. Add some condition regarding how much motion do you expect.

`fs.dx` and `fs.dy` will give you all the points where motion has been detected.

I have made an example in which I take input from camera and by detecting horizontal and vertical motion, I control Banshee Media Player. you can find it here on my [GitHub](https://github.com/jayrambhia/SimpleCVexamples/blob/master/banshee_control.py).

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called background subtraction:

[image: image is taken from the web]

*(image is taken from [this article](http://cnx.org/content/m19013/latest/))*

Take a look at [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026752/efficient-background-subtraction-with-opencv).

Also there are many articles/examples in OpenCV so just Google it.

Answer (score 1):

If the first image that you have is of the similar kind , you could find the absolute difference of all the images from the first and have a threshold to find the images that are significantly different.
Also in openCV , for detecting motion in a video , something like this can be done : 
http://sundararajana.blogspot.in/2007/05/motion-detection-using-opencv.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you by any chance have a code sample for finding the absolute difference between two images? Thanks!

Comment: In openCV , you have to first declare 2 matrices for the image, convert the image to greyscale , and then you can use the `absdiff()` function. You could look at http://www.developerstation.org/2011/03/frame-differencing-using-opencv-in-c.html for an example of the same.